# div moves out on page scroll down and in on scroll down

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm so close in getting this work like I want.

I have a plane that will fly off the screen (right:0, opacity:0) upon page scroll. 
Ideally, the div wouldn't start to animate until the page is scrolled down 170 pixels.

site: http://wp.ccrcc.org/

When the page is scrolled up with less than 300 pixels left before the top, the plane flies back in from the far left off screen back to the original position. I think I've got most of this working in my JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/VyU97/198/) code but it doesn't work on the Wordpress website:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function flyOut() {
        var previousScroll = 0;
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();

        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
                //            if (top > 170) {
                jQuery('#header-plane').animate({
                    right: '0',
                    opacity: 0
                }, 'slow', function () {});
                //            }
            } else {
                if (top < 300) {
                    jQuery('#header-plane').stop(true).animate({
                        right: '1000',
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 10, function () {
                        jQuery(this).animate({
                            right: '250',
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 1000, function () {});
                    });
                }
            }
            previousScroll = currentScroll;
        });
    }
}
$(window).scroll(function () {
    flyOut();
});
```

Comment: Did you check for errors? What did your console say?

Comment: The console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: flyout is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of changes to the JS so while I start typing the list here, you can see the corrected Fiddle:

## [Fixed plane demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ee7KV/)

**Breakdown of changes:**

- `$(window).scroll(function() { flyOut(); });` was redundant - condensed to `$(window).scroll(flyOut);`
- Need to keep animation from re-playing with variables designated to each offScreen for scrolldown and animated for scrollup).
- `previousScroll` was getting overwritten every scroll back to 0 so the scrollup animation would never fire.
- `var top = $(window).scrollTop()` is the same as `var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop()` so eliminated extra variable.

### Javascript

```
var animated = false,
    offScreen = false,
    previousScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(flyOut);

function flyOut() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (top > previousScroll) {
        if (top > 170 && offScreen === false) {
            animated = false;
            offScreen = true;
            jQuery('#header-plane').animate({
                right: 0,
                opacity: 0
            }, 'slow');
        }
    } else {
        if (top < 300 && animated === false && offScreen === true) {
            animated = true;
            offScreen = false;
            jQuery('#header-plane').animate({
                right: '1000px',
                opacity: 0
            }, 10, function () {
                jQuery(this).animate({
                    right: '250px',
                    opacity: 1
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
    }
    previousScroll = top;
}
```

Comment: I see you put this on your page but you forgot to remove the second `$(window).scroll()` that I mentioned in my breakdown (first item)

Comment: Yeah, I was reading too fast. I also had to replace all shortcuts $ with jQuery because of Wordpress. I works great now. Thanks for explaining my errors!

Comment: Anytime.  Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

On the WP website, in Firebug Console I have the following script error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

$(window).scroll(function () {
```

It looks like you've missed closing off your first document ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {} );
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That needed to be fixed but it's still not working on the browser after adding the missing );